# Run a SQL Query to change all published WooCommerce product to draft status

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to run a `SQL` query through my `functions.php` file and once that works, move it into a plugin and that way, by activating it the query will run. I can then run the query by activating / deactivating the plugin.

The goal is to change ALL products with the status `published` into `drafts`. Here's what I got, which does not work.

Anyone here who can help?

```
add_action('wp_head','turn_all_products_into_drafts');
function turn_all_products_into_drafts(){
    include_once("wp-config.php");
    include_once("wp-includes/wp-db.php");
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'draft' WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'";
                    $wpdb->update($sql);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have spelling error ?
In description you say :

> with the status **published**

and then in select you have :

> post_status = '**publish**'